# Split Float & Replace Integer PHP

Tags: php

I have float values in an array... Let's say one of my values is:

5.1234

How do I SWAP the integer in the float. So in the example above, I'd like to swap the 5 with 8. Therefore the new number would be:

8.1234

This needs to be a SWAP, not a mathematical addition as in 5.1234 + 3.

I basically need to split the number in two, the integer (5) and the float value following it (.1234), swap the 5 for the 8 and the recombine them to get 8.1234.

What is the fastest and most elegant way to do this in PHP since I'll be using this on a LOT of data?

To clarify WHY math cannot be used: This is because this is an obj file that's looking for an usemtl library title (Mudbox compliant) from which it extracts the UV space. Then it changes the vert U (or V) accordingly. Problem is these faces may come up more than once. This would make the operation cumulative, which it is NOT. All it needs to do is substituted the integer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php
    $number = 5.1234;
    $array = explode(".", $number);
    // $array[0] contains 5
    $newNumber = 8;
    $array[0] = $newNumber;
    $finalString = $array[0] . '.' . $array[1];
    $finalFloat = floatval($finalString); // String to float

    echo $finalFloat;

?>
```

Here is how I would do this. This solution is relevant if you are sure the number will always be formated like followed :

[number].[decimals]

Else you will not be able to always replace the number before the dot.

Comment: Thank you - didn't know you can explode a number like a string from its decimal point! :)

Comment: In fact you can't by using split() so your request is understandable, I had learn something too !